# Getting importing errors using when trying to useContext hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am having error below when i try to build my react app. I have object i want to get the update be managed by global context.[image: screenshoot of my message error]

I will include the code of my components:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const MoviesDataContext = createContext();

export default function GlobalMoviesProvider ({children})  {

  const [movie, setMovie] = useState({
    title: 'my test',
    release_date:'here we are ',
    rating:'ouh'
  });
  const value = {
    movie,
    setMovie,
  }
  return (
      <MoviesDataContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
      </MoviesDataContext.Provider>
    );
}
import React, {useContext} from 'react';

import {MoviesDataContext} from './MoviesDataContext';

const ButtonModalUpdater = () => {
    const {movie} = useContext(MoviesDataContext);
    console.log(movie);
    return (
        <h1></h1>
        
        
    );
    
};

export default ButtonModalUpdater;
import React, {createContext, useState} from "react";
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import {ButtonModalUpdater} from './ButtonModalUpdater'
import GlobalMoviesProvider from './MoviesDataContext'


function App() {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState(
    [
      {id:1, title:'comming to america', rating:5, release_date:'2020-12-22'},
      {id:2, title:'Instant Family', rating:3, release_date:'1995-12-22'},
      {id:3, title:'The Dig', rating:3, release_date:'2009-05-24'},
      {id:4, title:'The Wonder', rating:4, release_date:'2012-07-12'},
      {id:5, title:'The Rampage', rating:3, release_date:'2012-10-07'},
    ]
  ); 

  const [directors, setDirectors] = useState(
    [
     {first_name: 'Desiree', family_name: 'Akhavan', address: 'Oneroadstreet New York City'},
     {first_name: 'Chris', family_name:'John Barfoot', address: 'Somewherein the UK'},
     {first_name: 'Benjamin Geza', family_name:'Affleck-Boldt', address: 'Berkeley california'},
     {first_name: 'John', family_name:'Berry', address: 'The Bronx, New York'},
     {first_name: 'Terence', family_name:'Fisher', address: 'Maid vale, County of London, England'}
    ]
  );


  return (
    <GlobalMoviesProvider>
      <div className="App">
      <h1> Movie data Application</h1>
      <ButtonModalUpdater  />
       </div>
    </GlobalMoviesProvider>
  );

    
    
}

ReactDom.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById("root"));
```

I have tried to find out whether i have an import i have forgotten but was unseccessful in getting the error to be fixed. I do not know if there is anyone who could tips me in what might be wrong with the code.

Comment: try createContext(null)

Comment: This is causing issue `import {ButtonModalUpdater} from './ButtonModalUpdater'` .You have exported `ButtonModalUpdater` as default but importing as named export. Change it to `import ButtonModalUpdater from './ButtonModalUpdater'`

Comment: cheers it has fixed it